# Adding keys on components with no explicit key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the error:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key"

This is cos I am looping and creating components with no unique keys.

So I add the key as follows which just silences the error.

Are keys always going to exist for a new component, is this the correct solution?

I understand tags like `<div>` and `<h1>` will take in a key prop so it makes sense.

But `Element` is a component I created and I did not add a `key` prop.

Auto completion in `Webstorm` doesn't detect the key prop either. Yet it works.

Did try `ChatGPT` and it actually suggests I should explicitly add a key prop.

I am confused why it is working if that is the case.

Looking to understand if this is the correct solution.

As in, just add the key prop and it will just work. Pls advice.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {
        [0, 1, 2, 3].map((count) => {
          return <Element count={count} key={count} />
        })
      }
    </>
  )
}

const Element = ({ count }) => {
 return (
  <>
    {`I am an Element: ${count}`}
  </>
 );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for unique key Prop

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {
        [0, 1, 2, 3].map((count,index) => {
          return <Element count={count} key={count + '' + index} />
        })
      }
    </>
  )
}

const Element = ({ count }) => {
 return (
  <>
    {`I am an Element: ${count}`}
  </>
 );
};
```

In map functiion first parameter is array index Value and second is  Array index Number, Array Index Number are always unique.